# Why query with declare statement and parameter added to command object is working with library 15.5 but is not working with library 15.7?

Tags: c#, sybase

I have few applications working with Sybase and using version 15.5 of Sybase.Data.AseClient library without any problems. Recently I updated Sybase provider to version 15.7 and start receiving exceptions. Below is simplified C# code which is using declare statement in query along with AseParameter added to AseCommand object. Code is working with library 15.5 (2.155.8000.0) but is returning AseException "Must declare variable '@customer'" with library 15.7 (2.157.104.0)

Any info or ideas?

```
    string sql = @"
declare @purchaseDate datetime
set @purchaseDate = convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 101)
select count(*) from purchases where customer = @customer and purchaseDate > @purchaseDate
";

using (AseConnection cnn = new AseConnection(cnnStr))
{
    cnn.Open();
    using (AseCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = sql

        AseParameter par = cmd.CreateParameter();
        par.ParameterName = "@customer";
        par.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        par.AseDbType = AseDbType.VarChar;
        par.Size = 30;
        par.Value = customerId;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(par);

        int cnt = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    }
}
```